# Why do I get the error "Incorrect syntax near 'RESULT'" but renaming the CTE works fine?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I found this query for returning nth highest salary in sql server.

```
WITH RESULT
     AS (SELECT salary,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) AS DENSERANK
         FROM   Employees)
SELECT salary
FROM   RESULT
WHERE  RESULT.DENSERANK = 2
```

When I changed RESULT to RESULTS it is working, but RESULT is not working... WHY?

I am using SQL SERVER 2012

Comment: table name is Employee... @scaisEdge

Comment: @Ajay2707 I don't know, I just followed a video... I did what he did, but when I tried to change name, the error comes

Comment: It works just fine also with RESULT. see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/65577/1

Comment: Did you change the name in the `WITH` statement and the `FROM` statement and the `WHERE` statement?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes I changed in every occurrence....

Comment: @JamesZ Please see this picture... http://tinypic.com/r/24mfc55/9....

Comment: @JamesZ - Not on versions of SQL Server 2012 < SP1.

Answer (score 7):

[This issue is also mentioned here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/997289/Error-occurs-when-CTE-Alias-is-RESULT-Incorrect-sy). I can reproduce this on builds 11.0.2100.60 (SQL Server 2012 RTM) to 11.0.2424.0 (Cumulative Update 11)

[image]

But it is fixed in 11.0.3000.0 (Service Pack 1)

SQL Server 2012 introduced the `WITH RESULT SETS` syntax - which one might speculate caused the problem.